# How can I delete or uninstall Office 2011 Clip Art in Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, uninstall, microsoft-office-2011

(OS X Lion 10.7.2)

I want to uninstall or delete all the clip-art from my Office 2011 installation. I don't think I have the original dmg file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Mac-Uninstall](http://www.mac-uninstall.com/) and /or [AppZapper](http://appzapper.com/).

Both are made specifically for completely deleting programs and apps from mac computers.